# Get particular days from date range using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, range

I will provide two dates, as a range e.g 5th Oct 2016 to 5th December 2016, And 5th Oct was Wednesday so return me all the Wednesdays till 5th December 2016.

How can this be possible using Javascript or AngularJS ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you use any other library for date manipulations - such as momentJS for example?

Comment: nopes not using any lib. I m using flex calendar lib for showing calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not completely sure what you want to do, I think this will give you enough to work with:

```
var startdate = new Date("2016-10-05");
var enddate = new Date("2016-12-05");
var wednesdays = [];
while (startdate <= enddate) {
    wednesdays.push(startdate);
    // add a week
    startdate = new Date(startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + 7));
}
console.log(wednesdays);
```

Comment: Thanks! You are amazing man. Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Only edit is, that we should use do-while loop because in while it is also exceeding one week from the end date given